# Regex with required text matches in the string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to the smtp relay from the sendmail logs and to make it reliable I need to require multiple strings in the log entry.  An example of a log file entry would be like this:

```
2018-02-20T19:35:35+00:00 mx01.example.org sendmail[12345]: v1k82343VJ8K: to=<user@foobar.com>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, tls_verify=OK, relay=mailserver1.foobar.com. [1.1.1.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

I can't just key in on "relay=" because the particular relay name I need only appears in the log entry line that contains "to=" with it.

How do I write my regex so that:

1. The words "sendmail", followed by "to=", then followed by "relay=" all appear in the same log entry.
2. After "relay=" I match any letter, digit, and character until the comma.

The end result should be:

```
mailserver1.foobar.com. [1.1.1.1]
```

Comment: Which language?

Comment: pcre, it'll be used for field extractions in splunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/kNjQA6/2)

```
^.*\bsendmail\b.*\bto=.*relay=\K[^,]*
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `.*` Match any character any number of times
- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `sendmail` Match this literally
- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `.*` Match any character any number of times
- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `to=` Match this literally
- `.*` Match any character any number of times
- `relay=` Match this literallyl
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `[^,]*` Match any character except `,` any number of times

Result: `mailserver1.foobar.com. [1.1.1.1]`